# How do I decrease echo in an audio file using ffmpeg?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, ffmpeg

I was using ARSS to convert audio to spectrograms then back. However, my files 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1X24eUOzOGa5uBUHFTtrSmzptIQTz-93l
are all echoey. How do I reduce the echo/reverb using ffmpeg or anything command line interface(for python scripting)?
Note: I can upload originals if necessary

I have tried altering ARSS setting, mainly the brightness, however, 2.25 is the highest I can push it without introducing static, which would be even harder to remove, on top of the echo.